# How can I separate my stylesheets by class?

Tags: css

What I mean to say with this is, if I have a page with two divs, and I want each div to have a separate style, what way would I go about this?

Example:

```
div{ background: red;} // apply this style to one div.
div{ background: blue;} //apply this style to another div.
```

I realize it would be possible to just add a class to each div, but what if I expand it? What if I want a whole section of my page with a lot of different attributes to use one part of the stylesheet, and another whole section to use another part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply prefix the CSS rules with the ID or class of the section. For example:

```
#section1 h1 {
    color: red;
}

#section2 h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

and basically prefix every rule with either `#section1` or `#section2` depending on the containing section.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Now, in my HTML, how would I apply a section to the div?

Comment: To give an ID to your div, just do that: `<div id="section1"></div>` then the CSS rule above will apply to this div.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it you want for example every div in your header to be green while every div in your footer is supposed to be red.

```
#header div{ background-color: green; }
```

And than

```
<div id="header">
    <div>I'm green</div>
</div>
```

You can also use more complex selectors to helpt you solve special cases, take this example:

```
#header div{ background-color: red; }
#header > div{ background-color: green; }
```

And than

```
<div id="header">
    <div>
        I'm green...
        <div>...and I'm red</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Microsoft has a [great overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#selectors) of what selectors are available. There examples are sometimes a little weak but its something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
.firstSectionType div{ background: red;} // apply this style to one div.
.firstSectionType span { color: blue; }
.secondSectionType div{ background: blue;} //apply this style to another div. 
.secondSectionType span {color: red; }
```

Then if your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="firstSectionType">
    <p><span>Hello</span></p>
    <div>This has a red background and <span>this is blue text</span></div>
</div>
<div class="secondSectionType">
    <p><span>Hello</span></p>
    <div>This has a blue background and <span>this is red text</span></div>
</div>
```

the `div`s and `span`s in the corresponding secions will be formatted accordingly.

The CSS above requires you to repeat `.firstSectionType` or `.secondSectionType` in each rule, but a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) will allow you to rewrite it like:

```
.firstSectionType
{
    div{ background: red;} // apply this style to one div.
    span { color: blue; }
}
.secondSectionType 
{
    div{ background: blue;} //apply this style to another div. 
    span {color: red; }
}
```